# Robocopy "invalid parameter" in shell script

Tags: shell, remote-access, git-bash, remote-server, robocopy

I'm trying to use robocopy to move files to a remote machine. This is being done on a Windows machine through a file `script.sh` that is executed inside Git Bash.

### Background

First I use `net use` to add the shared directory:

```
NET USE \\\\$DEPLOY_SERVER\\$DEPLOY_SHARE /user:$DEPLOY_SERVER\\$DEPLOY_USER $DEPLOY_PASS
```

This works fine.

### Issue

Then I go to copy the files with `robocopy`:

```
robocopy . \\\\$DEPLOY_SERVER\\$DEPLOY_SHARE\\$DEPLOY_DIR /MIR
```

which fails with **error code 16**.

From [the robocopy docs](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html), 16 is `Serious error. Robocopy did not copy any files.Either a usage error or an error due to insufficient access privileges on the source or destination directories.`

Running it without `/MIR` works fine with no errors.

#### Error log

When run with `/MIR` I get the error:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
Started : Mon Dec 18 15:46:26 2017    
Source - C:\<path to current dir>\
 Dest - \\<deploy server>\<deploy share>\<deploy dir>\    
Files :
Options : /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
ERROR : Invalid Parameter #3 : "C:/Users/<my user>/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/MIR"    
   Simple Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination /MIR    
         source :: Source Directory (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
    destination :: Destination Dir  (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
           /MIR :: Mirror a complete directory tree.    
For more usage information run ROBOCOPY /?    
****  /MIR can DELETE files as well as copy them !
```

#### Further error description

This happens for any options, not just `/MIR`, this is just the simplest form of the error.

I've read many questions very similar to this, the common answer is to put your paths in double quotes in case there are spaces. My paths do not have spaces but I've tried that as well and got the same error. Additionally this would result in the "Source" and "Dest" paths in the `robocopy` output to be incorrect, but they are correct for me.

I have no idea why I would be going to that `git` directory and looking for `MIR`, or why it's not just parsing the options correctly. Additionally I checked and `MIR` does not exist inside `C:/Users/<my user>/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/`.

### Research

Other questions that are similar but didn't help me:

- [invalid parameter in robocopy syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383917/invalid-parameter-in-robocopy-syntax)
- [Robocopy showing invalid parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29575512/robocopy-showing-invalid-parameter)
- [robocopy invalid parameter “-”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30160259/robocopy-invalid-parameter)
- [Robocopy Invalid Parameter #7 Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418395/robocopy-invalid-parameter-7-log)
- https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22616754/Robocopy-Error-Invalid-Parameter-3.html
- [robocopy says its receiving invalid parameters in when used in powershell script](https://serverfault.com/questions/616725/robocopy-says-its-receiving-invalid-parameters-in-when-used-in-powershell-script)
- [Robocopy - Invalid Parameter](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/robocopy-invalid-parameter/4f127eae-27d9-4ebb-b8ad-8cef3827642a)
- [Robocopy invalid parameter #3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23195109/robocopy-invalid-parameter-3)

### Conclusion

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm also open to using something other than `robocopy`, but it would need to work with a remote machine, be runnable from a shell script, support mirroring, and not use `ssh`(`net use` works for robocopy so ideally something else like that).

Comment: The [tag:shell] tag (and "shell script" phrasing) is not typically used for questions about Windows -- as the description says, questions containing that tag are generally about POSIX-family shells on UNIXlike operating systems. Perhaps you should be tagging [tag:cmd] or [tag:powershell] (as appropriate) instead? (Or if this is being run in Cygwin or msys bash, please specify that explicitly).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks! I added it to the top, this is on a Windows machine, but it's run inside Git Bash or using sh.exe.

Comment: Which of those two? Even if `/bin/sh` in the same binary as Git Bash, it runs in POSIX mode when started with that name, so it's a different featureset exposed.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the error occurs either way, but for the question I'm going with Git Bash, and the question has been updated accordingly

Comment: If you run `bash -x yourscript`, does the output differ materially from what you'd expect? (If, for instance, the log says it's passing `$'/MIR\r'` instead of `/MIR`, that's an example of the kind of difference that would be expected to cause this problem -- and implies that your script was saved with DOS newlines instead of UNIX ones; incidentally, that's literally the *very first thing* that the [`bash` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) says to check for in the section *"Before asking about problematic code"*).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yep I checked that as well, and the line looked fine: `robocopy <source> <dest> /MIR /ns /nc /ndl /np`, no funky characters or anything

Comment: Just for a sanity check I did `tr -d '\r' < script.sh > script_new.sh` and then `cat -v script_new.sh` to confirm that there definitely isn't the `^M` character, then `bash -x script_new.sh` and saw the same error, with the line in question ending up the same way as well

Answer (score 4):

I got it working by escaping the /MIR Parameter with an extra forward slash:

```
robocopy "C:\source" "C:\destination" //MIR
```

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

It happens when need admin `privileges/` or pop to create file into that directory

So try to have a `log/temp` directory and try to add `log` file into that `log` directory

```
mkdir log\
e.g: robocopy . \\\\$DEPLOY_SERVER\\$DEPLOY_SHARE\\$DEPLOY_DIR 
/log:"\\$ServerShare\log\copy_log.log"
```